# Best way to scroll HTML page to given anchor in a responsive page

Tags: html, css

I have created a page based on this responsive template

```
https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/phantom/
```

I would like the blocks to have an anchor on the same page: when you click on it, it shows you the content (no redirect to a different page)

What is the best "modern" way to achieve this? plain anchor link/jquery/css other?

Can you show me an example?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way according to me is to place the target content on the same page  with an ID(obviously unique) `<div id="generic"> ..content.. </div>` and on your `<a>` tag's `href`, target the required div with the ID with `href="#generic"`. like so

```
<a href="#generic">
  <h2>Magna</h2>
  <div class="content">
     <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit ame.</p>
  </div>
</a>
.....
.....
.....
<div id="generic">..</div>
```

Additional to this add smooth scrolling to make it look like its sliding up/down to the targeted content.

To not add the `#generic` to your url try using a super simple JQuery fix additional to the above code:

```
$("article a").click(function(e){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500);
    e.preventDefault(); //this is the important line.
});
```

I have tested this on your website & it works like a charm! Let me know if any issues.

Comment: To me it looks like the basic anchor link (href to id) does not scroll to the precise place. And I am pretty sure this does not work very well in mobile responsive.

Comment: Well actually it does :-) You can have a look at my own website's menu on how it works [here](http://nikhilnanjappa.github.io/)

Comment: How to hide the #part in the url? when I click in your navbar on the link it does not add #, how to do that?

Comment: I have written couple of JQuery lines for that part. I have updated my answer. Check it out

Comment: surely if your id is unique, you wouldn't name it `generic` ? `:-D`

Comment: Hahah nice observation...That was the code he used in his project, so took that as an example :-D

Answer (score 0):

Google... single page application(SPA) I know it is possible using AngularJS etc. but there might me some solutions to achieve this only with Jquery/Javascript

Take a look at [Architecture for single page application (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245935/architecture-for-single-page-application-javascript)

Also take a look at http://singlepageappbook.com/single-page.html

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of possibilities to do so, the easiest and most dumb way is create and anchor link like this:

```
<a href="#myContainerId">To my container</a>
```

In which the href is the id of the container you want to reach with the click. Of course this method jumps without any animation.
A good example of an animated scrolling with anchor is found here:

[CSS tricks smooth scroll](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Let me know if that helps.

Cheers